# Android 13 POST_NOTIFICATIONS request permission dialog not showing

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-permissions, android-13

I usually add a post_notification permission request to my app.
The strange thing is that when I request directly, the dialog will not pop up.
But if I create the Notification channel first, I can jump out of the dialog normally,
Has anyone encountered the same situation? Or is there something wrong with my settings? Thanks!

AndroidManifest.xml
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />`

Fragement:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        requestPermissionLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) {
                if (it) {
                    LogUtil.d(TAG, "Grant POST_NOTIFICATION permission")
                } else {
                    LogUtil.d(TAG, "Denied POST_NOTIFICATION permission")
                }
            }

    }
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    override fun onResume()
    {
       if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                activity!!.applicationContext,
                Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS,
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
        ) {
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
        }
    }
```

**Situation 1**

if I add `createNotificationChannel()` before request permisssion,it work.

```
private fun createNotificationChannel() {
    val channel = NotificationChannel(
        CHANNEL_ID,
        "Important Notification Channel",
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH,
    ).apply {
        description = "This notification contains important announcement, etc."
    }
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
}
```

**Situation 2**

When I mark `createNotificationChannel()`,the dialog would not showing anymore.

After adding the Log, I found that,
After executing requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS),
there is no log jumping out,
just get the return of registerForActivityResult = false,
but I opened the app for the first time, and I have not rejected the notifcaiton permission.

I want to know how to fix it?

Comment: Could you solve it? I have the same issue, maybe it's Android bug...

Answer (score 0):

##### Step # 1

Can you change this

```
== PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
```

to

```
!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

##### Step # 2

Ask for `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale`, if user denies permission for once, on this official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Comment: I tried this,but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and had forgotten to update my gradle build files to set the target SDK to 33.  Updating the target SDK fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your target SDK is 33 or higher